# What data does /sys/module/notes hold?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, sysfs

I want to know what type of data the `notes` subdir holds in a specific `/sys/module` entry, however the `man 5 sysfs` of `/sys/module` is not fully documented yet. There must be some documentation around it but I have trouble finding any through my favorite search engine, is there any public documentation of these sub directories?

```
$ man 5 sysfs
/sys/module
notes  [To be documented]
```

Answer (score 2):

I’m not aware of any documentation other than [the commit message introducing the feature](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6d76013381ed28979cd122eb4b249a88b5e384fa):

> This patch adds the `/sys/module/<name>/notes/` magic directory, which has a
> file for each allocated `SHT_NOTE` section that appears in `<name>.ko`.  This
> is the counterpart for each module of `/sys/kernel/notes` for `vmlinux`.
> Reading this delivers the contents of the module's `SHT_NOTE` sections.  This
> lets userland easily glean any detailed information about that module's
> build that was stored there at compile time (e.g.  by `ld --build-id`).

Module notes are usually the build-id (`.note.gnu.build-id`) and the kernel version for which the module was built (`.note.Linux`).

(`SHT_NOTE` sections are [section of ELF files](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).)